# json file can only take integer or slice formatting not string

Tags: python

I have a problem running the code below,at line the t**one_freq = tone_map[tone_name** it brings error that list indices must be integers or slices not string

A sample of the Json at the commented tones website is

```
[
 {
   "432": "Note",
   "434": "Frequency (Hz)",
   "436": "Wavelength (cm)",
   "438": "",
   "440": "",
   "442": "",
   "444": "",
   "446": ""
  },
 {
   "432": "C0",
   "434": "16.35",
   "436": "2109.89",
   "438": "",
   "440": "",
   "442": "",
   "444": "",
   "446": ""
  },
 {
   "432": "C#0/Db0",
   "434": "17.32",
   "436": "1991.47",
   "438": "",
   "440": "",
   "442": "",
   "444": "",
   "446": ""
  },
```

The python code am using to synthesize tones to generate music is this.i have converted the html table at http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html to a json file that am using but says it have to be integer or slice

```
import json

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

# Synthesize the tone based on the input parameters
def tone_synthesizer(freq, duration, amplitude=1.0, sampling_freq=44100):
# Construct the time axis 
    time_axis = np.linspace(0, duration, duration * sampling_freq)

# Construct the audio signal
    signal = amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * time_axis)

    return signal.astype(np.int16) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Names of output files
    file_tone_single = 'generated_tone_single.wav'
    file_tone_sequence = 'generated_tone_sequence.wav'

    # Source: http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html
    mapping_file = 'tone_mapping.json'

   # Load the tone to frequency map from the mapping file
with open(mapping_file, 'r') as f:
    tone_map = json.loads(f.read())

# Set input parameters to generate 'F' tone
tone_name = 'F'
duration = 3     # seconds
amplitude = 12000
sampling_freq = 44100    # Hz

# Extract the tone frequency
tone_freq = tone_map[tone_name]

# Generate the tone using the above parameters
synthesized_tone = tone_synthesizer(tone_freq, duration, amplitude, sampling_freq)

# Write the audio signal to the output file
write(file_tone_single, sampling_freq, synthesized_tone)

# Define the tone sequence along with corresponding durations in seconds
tone_sequence = [('G', 0.4), ('D', 0.5), ('F', 0.3), ('C', 0.6), ('A', 0.4)]

# Construct the audio signal based on the above sequence 
signal = np.array([])
for item in tone_sequence:
    # Get the name of the tone 
    tone_name = item[0]

    # Extract the corresponding frequency of the tone
    freq = tone_map[tone_name]

    # Extract the duration
    duration = item[1]

    # Synthesize the tone
    synthesized_tone = tone_synthesizer(freq, duration, amplitude, sampling_freq)

    # Append the output signal
    signal = np.append(signal, synthesized_tone, axis=0)

# Save the audio in the output file
write(file_tone_sequence, sampling_freq, signal)
```

Comment: Error in line number..?

Comment: Is the "sample of the Json" your "tone_mapping.json" file ? If yes, it's not a mapping (`dict`) but a list of dicts.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you cannot get element from list providing it's index as string. This is not a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

From the python documentation:

> json.loads(s[, encoding[, cls[, object_hook[, parse_float[, parse_int[, parse_constant[, object_pairs_hook[, **kw]]]]]]]])
>
> Deserialize s (a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.
>
> If s is a str instance and is encoded with an ASCII based encoding other than UTF-8 (e.g. latin-1), then an appropriate encoding name must be specified. Encodings that are not ASCII based (such as UCS-2) are not allowed and should be decoded to unicode first.

As you can understand from the error, `tone_map` is a list.
try this:

`for i in tone_map:
    tone_freq = i[tone_name]`

Store tone_freq in a list and work with it

`tone_frequencies = list()
for i in tone_map:
    tone_frequencies.append(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is that you used to convert the HTML table (http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html) into JSON seems to have done this in a format that is quite inconvenient for what you need. If you look at the JSON document, it is an array (not a map/dict). The array elements seem to correspond to the original table rows and and each array element itself is a dict, containing the keys "432", "434", "436", "438", etc. The first three of those are the table's three columns (name, frequency, wavelength) and the rest are empty.

You should first try to re-format this into something more useful, e.g., a map between note names and frequencies (don't forget to convert the frequency data to a float - the JSON doc has it as string). Maybe something like this will do:

```
name_column="432"
freq_column="434"
fmap = { row[name_column] : float(row[freq_column]) for row in json_doc[1:] }
```

(note I have sliced off the 1st array element, which contains the column names)

now, you can try:

```
freq = fmap["E0"]
print (freq)
```

Also, note in your sample Python code you use note names like "C", this isn't found in your table (it has "C0", "C1", etc).